# aws load balancer for computation on multiple nodes (a render farm)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm fairly new to aws but from what I've learned so far load balancer takes a request and forwards it to some node. What I'm looking for is a scenario in which user sends one request (e.g. render 1000 frames of some animation) and load balancer then sends to individual nodes chunks of computation to perform (node A renders first 10 frames, node B renders next 10 frames and so on, and if node B fails then some other node will still render frames 10-20 and nothing gets lost). Is this even a job for load balancer? How do you go about implementing such a system? If there is some tutorial/book/course/etc I'd be thankful for any recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Elastic Load Balancers (ELB) are not meant for that. Instead you can try something like [Render Farm Deployment Kit on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rfdk/latest/guide/what-is-rfdk.html).

Comment: I actually already tried rfdk and I keep getting strange bugs coming from library itself that nobody knows how to fix plus I had to downgrade cdk version just to make things compile. I'm tired of it and want to write my own render farm in pure ec2. After all, rfdk also uses a load balancer, so there should be some way.

Comment: In that case, AFAIK, you would need to implement a custom solution for that.